# Getting System error code of 126 in Informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica

The setup routine for the BMC ODBC for Oracle(default) Odbc driver couldn't be loaded due to system error 126. The specified module could not be found. 
I'm getting this error in imformatica 9.5.1 
Can anyone suggest any solution..

Comment: can you use  DataDirect ODBC ? This comes with informatica client and server.